# Styling of SVG symbols on a per-use basis

Tags: svg, cross-browser, css-selectors

As demonstrated at http://jsfiddle.net/xMnea/4/ I have defined a symbol that contains multiple elements, each with its own class attribute. In the main body I use the symbol multiple times. I am using in-line CSS to style each use individually.

In Firefox 15 this works as expected, but in IE9 and Chrome, I get black squares. It appears that the latter browsers don't detect/recognise the class definitions within the symbol. They work as expected if the structure is in-line (bottom right square).

Is this simply a case of Firefox being more compliant than the others, or is there a better way to achieve reuse of SVG elements while allowing individual styling?

extra info: The same problem occurs if I use "defs" rather than symbol, or if I use external style sheets rather than in-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's Firefox is less compliant due to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=265894

If you want reuse and individual styling there's a javascript approach that may eventually be implemented natively by UAs [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/)

Comment: That's disappointing! I first used the technique in hope as much as in knowledge, and when it worked on Firefox I thought nothing further of it...until...

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#UseElement states the following:

"For user agents that support Styling with CSS, the conceptual deep cloning of the referenced element into a non-exposed DOM tree also copies any property values resulting from the CSS cascade ([CSS2], chapter 6) on the referenced element and its contents. CSS2 selectors can be applied to the original (i.e., referenced) elements because they are part of the formal document structure. CSS2 selectors cannot be applied to the (conceptually) cloned DOM tree because its contents are not part of the formal document structure."